# How to specify the use of LAN network?

Tags: python, sockets, lan

`server.py`

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1314))
```

I used the IP address 0.0.0.0 to use the local IP, but it seems to be connecting to the external IP address 26.238.*.*. How can I control it to prevent it from accessing the external network?

I attempted to use 192.168.255.255, but it doesn't seem to work. -w-

Comment: The computer you are running the script on has an IP address in your LAN. Use this.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Is there no way to make it dynamic? This will require the user to manually enter...

Comment: The `psutils` library provides a way to list all network adapters and their IP addresses: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_if_addrs. From these addresses you have to find the local LAN address and use it. Unfortunately in more complicated configurations there may be more than one such address.

Comment: `'0.0.0.0'` binds the socket to all interfaces. Use `'localhost'` to only accept connections from processes on the server itself, or use the ip of a specific adapter, listed with the `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` utility